# Apache Nifi - Creating a flow to receive a file via HTTP POST and write the file system

Tags: file, post, apache-nifi

The question is pretty simple, and I have tried it in Nifi already and have it working but badly, so I am looking for a better way.

I want to send a file to Nifi via a REST API and have it write it to the filesystem.

I can use a HTTPListen Processer to listen for a HTTP call, and I can curl a file up to it. This then gets added to the flowfile as data.

I can then use a PutFile Processer to write the flowfile out to disk, but I then get all the metadata of the flow file with it.

My *horrible* solution right now is trimming the bytes off the head and tail of the file with a shell script. I feel like I must be missing a better way to do this, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Can you put some example of how the FlowFile looks like?

Comment: Are the any other processors between ListenHttp and PutFile? and if so, which ones?

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu, I cant the Nifi system is down for mainatince at the momment. So I was using the down time to try and find an alternative to current.

Comment: @BryanBende nope, ideally it will be Listen, put and then exectue a shell script, but for right now nothing in the middle.